# Writing Resources from filesystem in Android

Tags: android, resources

as I need to get a specific Frame from a Website I want to display in an WebView, I decided to grab the .html from the net and save it under file:///data/data//files/file.html. Stroed there I can edit it using regex or String methods.

Now two questions:
Is there a way to bind this file to an resource. e.g. to /res/raw/file.html and get it updated dynamically as i edit it? Or can i write the File directly to the resources?

Is this whole stuff I do there any good or performant at all? I mean maybe there is a better way to get the .html code between two tags from a Webpage and display it via WebView.

Kind regards
Markus

Answer (score 0):

I believe that application assets are readonly. So you cannot write anything to it.

You can though, get access to the internal (device memory) files directory and write your data there.  As for automatically updating the file, you'll have to take care of that in your code.

Here is an example of how you would go about writing a file (in my case a stream) to the files directory for your application

```
// ... code ...
// assumed variables:
// InputStream data, String directory, String filename
File storageLocation = new File(directory, filename)
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(storageLocation);
    byte[] buff = new byte[0x2000];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
    while( (bytesRead = data.read(buffer)) > 0) { dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); }
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: Actually handle the exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// ... more code ...
```

Comment: thanks i did this to write the file.html to file:///data/data//files/file.html but now i want to get this into the Resources of Android. The other problem is, i cant load the File using loadDataWithBaseURL....

Comment: If you know what the name of the file is (stored in shared preferences perhaps) you can then just grab the file by creating a file input stream by finding your files directory with this <a href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()">Context#getFilesDir</a>

Comment: Sorry, having an issue with the stack overflow comments for a URL with brackets in it.  Just look up getFilesDir under Context in the Android documentation.  That should help you out.